# Does a server ignore gzipped js files when gzipping?

Tags: gzip

Gidday

I have mod_deflate set up on my server, and it works well.

I'm minifying my js files with an online compressor, and it has an option to save them gzipped.

I was wondering if this is worthwhile - does it save server cpu by saving static files gzipped - does the server just ignore gzipping them and serve the gzipped file as it is saved?

Cheers